# Eclipse PDT: "<class> cannot be resolved to a type" for default php classes like DateTime, Exception etc

Tags: php, eclipse

After some recent Eclipse updates and workspaces changes I found some problems with validation of my PHP code in PDT. After re-adding all external libraries for my projects every external class was resolvable, but for PHP base classes like "DateTime" or "Exception" I get an error/annotation "DateTime cannot be resolved to a type". PHP Validation Version is set to 7.1, but even lower settings create the error.

How can I fix this validation problem?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are many possible situations here; mine was an quite old project having a broken buildpath configuration. However using the GUI I wasn't able to fix it.

Adding the following line to the .buildpath file in the project folder while eclipse was closed and afterwards restarting eclipse solves the problem:

`<buildpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.php.core.LANGUAGE"/>`

However, additionally if the code uses namespaces, one needs to use \DateTime instead of DateTime, or alternatively, add a 'use DateTime' on top;

(Solution found after digging deeper into comments of other problems using [Eclipse PDT does not propose all php functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39627770/eclipse-pdt-does-not-propose-all-php-functions) and https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=502184)

Comment: Unfortunately this does not fix my problem which looks the same. I just did a fresh install of Eclipse Oxygen2 via the Oomph 64-bit installer on a Windows 8.1 box with JRE 8u161, I have the same problem but the entry in `.buildpath` is already there?

Comment: Thank you, it works for me. I added a file .buildpath with this line and I have clean the project into Eclipse.

Comment: `However, additionally if the code uses namespaces, one needs to use \DateTime instead of DateTime, or alternatively, add a 'use DateTime' on top;` This was my problem. Changing `DateTime` to `\DateTime` fixed it for me.

Answer (score 6):

If you don't have a file called **.buildpath** in the root folder of your project, just create it.

The content of the file should be something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<buildpath>
    <buildpathentry kind="src" path=""/>
    <buildpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.php.core.LANGUAGE"/>
</buildpath>
```

That's going to assign all your folders as "source folders".

That works fine in **Eclipse Oxygen.3a Release (4.7.3a)**

Comment: The accepted solution does not mention that the `.buildpath` could be missing. It was the case for me.

Answer (score 2):

@NextThursday mentions using the global scope using '\' before the class name. This is only important if you code is already scoped inside a specific namespace.

Answer (score 2):

Mine is a little different but it worths mentioning here for the newcomer like me.
I just import project using `Import` > `Projects from Folder or Archive`. It's just a folder no more no less.
You have to right click on your imported folder > `Configure` > `Convert to PHP Project ...` 
 The Error on `Exception` is gone.

Comment: This option no longer exists, there is configure>  'convert to faceted form', 'Configure and detect nested projects', 'Add composer support', 'Convert to Javascript project'

Answer (score 1):

I recently ran into a similar situation with a project whose code is on a network server and the server went down. When it was restored the mounts had changed so some of my external libraries could not be found. This is how I fixed it:

In my project properties->php->source paths->include path libraries tab I added the paths to the external code. Then I ran Build project on my project followed by Refresh. The warnings went away.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I'm using the composer, then, the eclipse has an option to update the build path:

Composer -> Update Build Path

Comment: I already had .buildpath included from when it was imported, this worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem where vendored dependencies (from `vendor` folder) were unrecognized for a new project. E.g. if I had in code:

```
use \Psr\Log\LoggerAwareInterface
```

It'll be underlined red with a note that "*the import ... cannot be resolved*", and outside of imports these classes had "*cannot be resolved to a type*" with them.

Yet I had `.buildpath` in place, but if look closely you notice the problem:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<buildpath>
    <buildpathentry kind="src" path="examples"/>
    <buildpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
    <buildpathentry kind="src" path="tests"/>
    <buildpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.php.core.LANGUAGE"/>
</buildpath>
```

That's right, there's no entry for `vendor` folder. Adding missing entry:

```
    <buildpathentry kind="src" path="tests"/>
+   <buildpathentry kind="src" path="vendor"/>
    <buildpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.php.core.LANGUAGE"/>
```

And then cleaning/building the project fixed the problem right away.

Answer (score 0):

I have recently run into this problem by re-opening a working project the next day in Eclipse 2021-06...

What I did was disable all Validators, remove all Errors from the Problems view, and re-enabled Validators again. Then Project > Validate fixed it!

Edit: I saw that it created new file: `.settings/org.eclipse.wst.validation.prefs`

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes we didn't notice a missing ";" or "}" that could lead to this problem. So please check if there's any new introduced grammar error if the problem has never happened in the file before.